# Miscellaneous review exercise from Apostol

Tags: calculus

I'm having some difficulties with the following problem from Apostol "Calculus" Volume 1 (Section 5.11 Number 5) which states:

Given two functions $f$ and $g$ whose derivatives $f'$ and $g'$ satisfy the equations:
$$
(5.30)      f'(x) = g(x), g'(x) = -f(x), f(0) = 0, g(0) = 1
$$
for every x in some open interval $J$ containing $0$.

1. Prove that $f^2(x) +g^2(x) = 1$ for every $x$ in $J$.
2. Let $F$ and $G$ be another pair of functions satisfying $(5.30)$. Prove that $F(x) = f(x)$ and $G(x) = g(x)$ for every $x$ in $J$. (Hint: Consider $h(x) = [F(x) - f(x)]^2 + [G(x) - g(x)]^2$)
3. What more can you say about functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying
   $(5.30)$?.

My attempts at solutions (so far) have been as follows: 
for part (1), Let $h(x) = f^2(x) + g^2(x).$ Therefore 
$$
h'(x) = (f^2(x) + g^2(x))' = (f^2(x))'+(g^2(x))'
$$
$$
= 2f(x)f'(x) +2g(x)g'(x)
$$
$$
= 2f(x)g(x)-2f(x)g(x) = 0
$$
Consequently $h(x) = k, k = $ constant. Setting $x = 0$ concludes the proof.

For part 2 I calculated
$$
h(x) = [F(x) - f(x)]^2 + [G(x) - g(x)]^2 
$$
$$
= F^2(x) - 2F(x)f(x) + f^2(x) + G^2(x) - 2G(x)g(x) + g^2(x)
$$
$$
= (F^2(x) + G^2(x)) + (f^2(x) + g^2(x)) - 2(F(x)f(x)+G(x)g(x))
$$
$$
= 2 - 2(F(x)f(x)+G(x)g(x))
$$
It's here that I'm stuck. 
I can see that, using this approach, showing $F(x)f(x)+G(x)g(x) = 1$ would confirm $h(x) = 0$ and (essentially) complete the proof. 
Furthermore, that fact that I have not seen a use for $f(0) = 0, g(0) = 1$ makes me wonder if I'm seriously missing the point on this problem (perhaps an inductive approach? it's not clear to me how I would approach this problem inductively if that was the case)

As always, any suggestions and/or extra hints would be greatly appreciated.

ADDENDUM:
I can actually show that $F(x)f(x)+G(x)g(x) = k$, $k =$ constant by showing that the derivative of $F(x)f(x)+G(x)g(x)$ is equal to $0$. I'm still not convince that my approach is the correct approach.

Comment: I can't understand what you think you proved with respect to (1): you begin with an "if"...which is what has to be proved... **so??** The method seems promising, yet I can't see what I think is the punch line.

Comment: I think I see your point, Don. Consequently I think my approach to point (1) should be rephrased as follows:
<br/>

Comment: Scratch that I'll start again.I think I see your point, Don. Consequently I think my approach to point (1) should be rephrased as follows: Let $h(x) = f^2(x) + g^2(x).$ Therefore 
$$
h'(x) = (f^2(x) + g^2(x))' = (f^2(x))'+(g^2(x))'
$$
$$
= 2f(x)f'(x) +2g(x)g'(x)
$$
$$
= 2f(x)g(x)-2f(x)g(x) = 0
$$
Consequently $h(x) = k, k = $ constant. Setting k = 1 concludes the proof.

Comment: Exactly my point, @emjay: by showing the derivatives of both sides are equal you show the functions are the same up to an additive constant, and then you calculate that constant. Way to go. +1 . You should perhaps add your above comment into your question. And BTW: I think you meant "setting $\;x=0\;$ concludes the proof."

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio, your explanation really helped my understanding!